# Errors relating to dynamic memory when implementing deque: "free(): invalid pointer" and "malloc(): mismatching next->prev_size (unsorted)"

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, deque

**Edit:** The problem was solved by one of the commenters, just so that no one spends unnecessary time trying to find a bug.

---

I'm learning C++ and am writing a deque class just for practice. The deque is implemented as a two dimensional dynamic array. `push_front` pushes elements to the right of the last existing element on the bottom-most row in use.

I'm getting some errors relating to dynamic memory allocation that I really find hard to debug. The errors happen when calling `delete[]` in certain situations.  Due to the errors having to do with freeing memory, I think the problem lies within the `_deallocate_front(int n_rows)` or `allocate_front(int n_rows)` methods. When I comment out the line
`delete[] _row_ptr[row_i]; // Commenting this row makes test1 work!`
in the `_deallocate_front` method, `test1` works but not `test2`.

Here's a working example:
compiled with: `g++-10 -std=c++20 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -o main  main.cpp`

```cpp
//main.cpp

#include <iostream>

#include "deque.h"

using std::cout;

void test1()
{
  deque<int, 3> d{};

  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) d.push_front(i);
  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) d.pop_front();
}

void test2()
{
  deque<int, 3> d{};

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) d.push_front(i);
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) d.pop_front();
}

int main()
{
  DEBUG = true;

  test1(); // free(): invalid pointer
  // test2(); // malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)

  return 1;
}
```

```cpp
// deque.h

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>

#include "position.h"

bool DEBUG = false;

template <typename T, int RowSize>
class deque
{
public:
  deque();
  ~deque();

  void push_front(T elem);
  void pop_front();

  inline friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, deque<T, RowSize> const & deq)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < deq._size; ++i)
    {
      auto pos = deq._front_pos + i;
      os << deq._row_ptr[pos.row_i][pos.col_i] << " ";
      if( (pos.col_i == RowSize - 1) && (i < deq._size - 1) ) os << "\n";
    }
    return os;
  }

//private:
  int _size;
  T** _row_ptr;
  int _n_rows_allocated;
  position<RowSize> _front_pos;

  int _n_unused_rows_front() const;

  void _allocate_front(int);
  void _deallocate_front(int);

  void _put(T elem, int row_i, int col_i);
};

#include "deque.tcc"
```

```cpp
// deque.tcc

#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

using std::cout;

template <typename T, int RowSize>
deque<T, RowSize>::deque() : _size{0}, _front_pos{0, 0}
{
  _row_ptr = new T* [1];
  _row_ptr[0] = new T [RowSize];
  if(DEBUG) cout << "NEW[] row: default ctor: " << _row_ptr[0] << "\n";
  _n_rows_allocated = 1;
}

template <typename T, int RowSize>
deque<T, RowSize>::~deque()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < _n_rows_allocated; ++i)
  {
    if(DEBUG) cout << "DELETING[] row: destructor: " << _row_ptr[i] << "\n";
    delete[] _row_ptr[i];
  }
  delete[] _row_ptr;
}

/*
Allocate n_rows_to_add rows before the row of _front_pos.
*/
template <typename T, int RowSize>
void deque<T, RowSize>::_allocate_front(int n_rows_to_add)
{
  // Create temporary pointer so that we can delete _row_ptr.
  T** tmp_ptr = new T* [_n_rows_allocated + n_rows_to_add];
  int row_i;
  // Copy existing rows make the new row allocations:
  for(row_i = 0; row_i < _n_rows_allocated; ++row_i)
  {
    tmp_ptr[n_rows_to_add + row_i] = _row_ptr[row_i];
  }
  for(row_i = 0; row_i < n_rows_to_add; ++row_i)
  {
    tmp_ptr[row_i] = new T[RowSize];
    cout << "NEW[] row: _allocate_front: " << tmp_ptr[row_i] << "\n";
  }

  // Deallocate existing row pointers:
  delete[] _row_ptr;
  // Start pointing at the newly allocated rows instead:
  _row_ptr = tmp_ptr;
  _n_rows_allocated += n_rows_to_add;
}

/*
Deallocate n_rows starting from the "front" of the allocated rows, i.e.
the rows with the lowest indexes.
*/
template <typename T, int RowSize>
void deque<T, RowSize>::_deallocate_front(int n_rows)
{
  if(n_rows <= _n_rows_allocated)
  {
    int row_i;
    for(row_i = 0; row_i < n_rows; ++row_i)
    {
      if(DEBUG) cout << "DELETING[] row: _deallocate_front: " << _row_ptr[row_i] << "\n";
      delete[] _row_ptr[row_i]; // Commenting this row makes test1 work!
    }
    // Create new pointers to point at the remaining rows:
    T** tmp_ptr = new T* [_n_rows_allocated - n_rows];
    for(row_i = 0; row_i < _n_rows_allocated; ++row_i)
    {
      tmp_ptr[row_i] = _row_ptr[row_i + n_rows];
    }
    delete[] _row_ptr;
    _row_ptr = tmp_ptr;

    _n_rows_allocated -= n_rows;
    // We need to adjust the front position by the number of rows we deleted:
    _front_pos.row_i -= n_rows;
  }
  else
  {
    throw std::runtime_error("Can't deallocate more rows than have been allocated");
  }
}

template <typename T, int RowSize>
void deque<T, RowSize>::_put(T elem, int row_i, int col_i)
{
  _row_ptr[row_i][col_i] = elem;
  ++_size;
}

template <typename T, int RowSize>
void deque<T, RowSize>::push_front(T elem)
{
  if(DEBUG) cout << "push_front " << elem << "\n";

  // Change the front position to what will be the next front position after
  // the element has been pushed to the queue:
  _front_pos = _size == 0 ? _front_pos : _front_pos - 1;

  if(_front_pos.row_i < 0) // We are out of rows, need to allocate more.
  {
    _allocate_front(_n_rows_allocated);
    // The front position needs to be adjusted after deleting all rows before it:
    _front_pos.row_i += _n_rows_allocated;
  }
  _put(elem, _front_pos.row_i, _front_pos.col_i);
}

template <typename T, int RowSize>
void deque<T, RowSize>::pop_front()
{
  if(DEBUG) cout << "pop_front\n";

  if(_size <= 0)
  {
    throw std::runtime_error("Cannot pop from empty deque.");
  }

  // Try to avoid taking up to much unused memory. The condition is kind of
  // arbitrary for the moment.
  if(_n_rows_allocated > 1 && _n_unused_rows_front() > _n_rows_allocated / 2)
  {
    if(DEBUG) cout << "pop_front: deallocating " << _n_unused_rows_front() / 2 << " rows\n";
    _deallocate_front(_n_unused_rows_front() / 2);
  }

  --_size;
  ++_front_pos;
}

template <typename T, int RowSize>
int deque<T, RowSize>::_n_unused_rows_front() const
{
  return _front_pos.row_i;
}
```

```cpp
//position.h

// Putting definitions in header because I'm lazy

/*
Represents a position in the deque.
Incrementing takes it to the right or down to the start of the next row..
Decrementing takes it to the left or up to the end of the previus row.
 */
template <int RowSize>
struct position
{
  int row_i;
  int col_i;

  static position<RowSize> index_to_pos(int i)
  {
    return position<RowSize>
    {
      std::floor(static_cast<double>(i) / RowSize),
      ((i % RowSize) + RowSize) % RowSize
    };
  }

  inline position<RowSize> operator+(int offset) const
  {
    return index_to_pos(row_i * RowSize + col_i + offset);
  }

  inline position<RowSize> operator-(int offset) const
  {
    return operator+(-offset);
  }

  inline position<RowSize>& operator++()
  {
    *this = (*this) + 1;
    return *this;
  }

  inline position<RowSize>& operator--()
  {
    *this = (*this) - 1;
    return *this;
  }

  inline friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os, position const & pos)
  {
    return os << "{" << pos.row_i << ", " << pos.col_i << "}";
  }
};
```

Comment: part of learning C++ is to learn avoing manual memory managment. Don't use raw owning pointers. You could use a `std::vector` eg as underlying storage. If you do manage memory it is important to stick to the [rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: This looks strange: `std::floor(static_cast<double>(i) / RowSize)`. Are you aware that you get this for free just using integral division? `i / RowSize` results in the integral quotient without remainder (where the remainder is the result of the `i % RowSize`).

Comment: The second for loop of `_deallocate_front` goes past the boundaries of `tmp_ptr`.

Comment: @Botje thank youuu! That was the problem. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks for the input. I wanted it to work for negative numbers as well, `-2/3 == 0` but `std::floor(static_cast<double>(-2) / 3) == -1` when I compile.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I agree, but I would argue part of learning C++ is also learning how to use dynamic memory if necessary since it can always pop up in a code base (or an exam). But I am also learning how to prefer using the standard library :) I tried to post a smaller example than my full class to make it easier to debug.

Comment: I wonder a bit about the negative indices but didn't check in detail why you might need them. Even then, I would prefer a conditional over floating point arithmetic on integrals.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I can see where you're coming from, I will make sure to change it to a conditional instead, thanks.

Comment: Learn how to use the Address Sanitizer to catch those issues easier.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Wow, just tried it and it is amazing. Would have saved me hours! Thank you so much for the suggestion.